# RSpec failure: could not find table after migration...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I have a naked rails 3 app with one model, generated using `rails g model User`.

I've added a factory (using `factory_girl_rails`):

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.email "test@test.com"
  f.password "blah"
  f.password_confirmation "blah"
  f.display_name "neezer"
end
```

Then I've added one test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  subject { Factory :user }

  it "can be created from a factory" do
    subject.should_not be_nil
    subject.should be_kind_of User
  end

end
```

Then I *migrate my database* using `rake db:migrate`.

Then I run the test using `rspec spec`, and the test fails with the following:

```
Failures:

  1) User can be created from a factory
     Failure/Error: subject { Factory :user }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm confused, because I did just migrate my database, and my `schema.db` file reflects that there is a users table present, so what gives?

I know this is a beginner question, but banging my head against a wall isn't working...

```
factory_girl (1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (1.0.1)
rails (3.0.5)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try to execute

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

This should fix your tests db.

Comment: Do I need to run that whenever I make new migrations, or just does it just "bootstrap" the test database?

Comment: just once, it's like db:migrate, i actually always put it in a custom task that i make that migrates, loads fixtures, test db and more.

Comment: Any ideas of what to do if rake db:test:prepare *does not* fix the problem? :(

Comment: check your migration script too, just incase it's not defined properly. it means your table is indeed not created correctly.

Comment: When will I stop getting burned by this?? I think I need to tattoo `rake db:test:prepare` to the back of one of my hands.

Answer (score 2):

The point here is that `rspec` command doesn't execute migrations on your test database. and `rake db:migrate` only runs migrations in your current environment, probably `development`. Others environment like `production` and `test` ends without having those changes.

You can run

```
rake spec
```

That will prepare your testing db (drop and create using `schema.rb`) and run all tests.

As [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5264371/456814) suggested, this:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Will also setup your testing db, but you have to run the rspec command after that, so, personally I prefer the first option.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
For rails version > 4.1+ this solution will work as the current scenario.

but in Rails 4.1+, rake db:test:prepare is deprecated.
```

try using

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test (it will work for all version of rails)
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you added some explainations for your intension.