# Could not find table 'users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**UPDATE 4**

See solution below!

**Update 3 **

If anyone is actually still reading this (I appreciate it!) I've been struggling around my code today (yes still a noob and in chapter 11 of the ruby on rails tutorial).

I've supposedly reset back to my last commit:

```
$ cd rails_screencast/sample_app/
$ git reset --hard 2396c0d288d132ffc43c82d5cbbc736a5258eed2
HEAD is now at 2396c0d Micropost Validations
```

When I check the site on local host it actually shows a list of users and not an ERROR page but when I run the test suite (autotest with spork - I've reset those a few times too to be sure) I still get all errors such as these shown below. I'm very curious about the "Could not find table 'users'" as it is in EVERY error #

```
  108) Users signin success should sign a user in and out
     Failure/Error: user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:56:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.9872 seconds
108 examples, 108 failures
```

Time to keep on plugging and looking at all these errors, if anyone can offer any insight or hints or ideas what to check I would appreciate it! Or if you need additional information I can post that too (just be very specific to which files to see as I'm not totally fluent in the lingo as many are already)

**Update 2:**

It seems that my reset messed something up with the factory settings as sometimes all my errors are pointing to line 5 of my micropost_spec.rb file specifically @ the @user = Factory(:user) line...  almost like my factories file isn't linked to anything any more. I am wondering if a rake db:migrate would solve any of my problems... or just create new problems... I only have sample data filling in with faker

Any ideas?

Is it possible to revert my file system back to a previous commit and start over? ... when I was green

```
Failures:

  1) Micropost should create a new instance with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Micropost user associations should have a user attribute
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Micropost user associations should have the right associated user
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Micropost validations should have a user id
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Micropost validations should require nonblank content
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Micropost validations should reject long content
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Update 1:**

I'm getting errors from 4 to 6 to 111 all with a recurring theme of

```
 1) Micropost should create a new instance with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Specifically the "Could not find table 'users'" - I copied the code from the tutorial git for the micropost_spec.rb file but didn't seem to fix it- maybe someone can help direct me to what the table is referring to?

////////////////////////////////////// ORIGINAL BELOW ////////////////////////////////

I am working in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial lesson 11 and am trying to populate my db to show the microposts

when I did the rake db:populate command it gave me the following:

```
    macbook:sample_app macbook$ rake db:populate
(in /Users/macbook/rails_screencast/sample_app)
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
db/test.sqlite3 already exists
db/development.sqlite3 already exists
-- create_table("microposts", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0090s
-- add_index("microposts", ["user_id"], {:name=>"index_microposts_on_user_id"})
   -> 0.0074s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0243s
-- add_index("users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_users_on_email", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0094s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0167s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20110614132314, "db/migrate")
   -> 0.0432s
rake aborted!
Validation failed: Email is invalid
```

I ran it a couple times and kept getting the same error... when I visited the site on a browser it was like none of my sample users were there...

```
require 'faker'


namespace :db do 
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task :populate => :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
    admin = User.create!(:name => "Foo Bar",
                         :email => "foo@bar.com",
                         :password => "foobar",
                         :password_confirmation => "foobar")
   admin.toggle!(:admin)
    99.times do |n|
      name = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password = "password"
      User.create!(:name => name,
                   :email => email,
                   :password => password,
                   :password_confirmation => password)
    end

    User.all(:limit => 6).each do |user|
      50.times do
        user.microposts.create!(:content => Faker::Lorem.sentence(5))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

then I decided oh maybe rake db:reset will purge my sample database and I can run the populate again with fresh stuff... bad assumption

my test suite now shows:

```
Finished in 0.99915 seconds
111 examples, 111 failures
```

Now before I mess more stuff up I'm looking for some advice where to go next ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSpec failure: could not find table after migration...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264355/rspec-failure-could-not-find-table-after-migration)

Answer (score 118):

Michael (author of the railstutorial.org) responded to my email request!

*If you're missing a table when running the test suite, it's probably an indication that you need to run:*

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

YUP!! YAYYYY

```
Finished in 4.82 seconds
108 examples, 0 failures
```

CAKE TIME!

Comment: You sir, are a legend. I have been battling with for a few hours. I've been trying some suggested monkey patches and nothing has been working. I'm still a complete n00b and its been killing me. If I could upvote this 100 times I would. Thanks You

Comment: Same here, just chugging along through the rails tutorial and got stuck in the same place. Thanks! And thanks to Michael!

Comment: wow!  it's Feb 2013 and this helped me as well :D  Thank you.  -Student from Hacker School

Comment: Can anyone explain what db:test:prepare does?  Why don't I need to do this with my development database when I purge it?

Comment: [sure](https://makandracards.com/makandra/2945-preparing-your-test-database-mind-the-differences)

Answer (score 3):

The `db:populate` that you're showing does a `db:reset` itself, so doing it manually can't have caused any problem that wasn't already happening with the `db:populate`.

You can just delete your `db/*.sqlite3` files and start from fresh.  There's nothing obvious in that `db:populate` code which would explain why the email validation failed, you'd have to show the `User` model and the validations you have in there for us to diagnose that initial issue.

Comment: The accepted answer of 'rake db:test:prepare' did not work for me without first deleting the db files. Thanks!