# Could not find table 'objects' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, whenever

I encountered a problem when executing the scheduled job by whenever.

In my config/schedule.rb:

```
every 1.minutes do
  runner "Ubike.update"
end
```

The function works without errors in the console, but I got this error message in the log:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval': Could not find table 'ubikes' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:399:in `columns'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:217:in `columns_hash'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:14:in `columns_hash'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:278:in `find_one'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:268:in `find_with_ids'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:35:in `find'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3/lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:122:in `find'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
    from /Users/tsengdavid/Documents/Rails/BikeTraffic/app/models/ubike.rb:10:in `update'
    from (eval):1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:84:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I tried `rake db:test:prepare` from a similar question in "[Could not find table 'users'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345319/could-not-find-table-users)" but I still have the same problem.

Comment: so... Ubike is an ActiveRecord model? do you have a ubikes table anywhere? Have you missed running a `db:migrate`?

Comment: Is whenever running in the right Rails environment? Connecting to the right database?

Comment: Looks you are using sqlite as db. right?

Comment: Yes, I use sqlite as db. actually I don't know whats my current environment. I think its development because data are in development.sqlite3.

Comment: Still Could not find table 'ubikes' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) after rake db:migrate.
But in console or use web link to call the function works fine.